# Get data by id wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

### Problem

I have two different plugin tables and I want to get their value by sql. Problem is id where I cannot find connection which I can retrieve data.

### Table 1 (bdt_mappress_posts)

postid = 2 and mapid = 3

### Table 2 (bdt_mappress_maps)

mapid = 3 and obj = json

```
<? $postid = get_the_ID(); 
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT obj FROM bdt_mappress_maps INNER JOIN bdt_mappress_posts WHERE bdt_mappress_maps.mapid = bdt_mappress_posts AND   bdt_mappress_posts.postid ='.$postid); print_r($results);
 ?>
```

$postid returns me id of the post. The sql returns me empty value, I know sql but not so strong. If someone can help me or give related post which I can find answer. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: whic is the relation between the two tables  ?... which are the columns for join?  update your question and add the tables schema

Comment: one table is contain postid second one is not and I want to get data by id

Comment: if the two table ahve not relation .. is not possible  .. be sure that the two table have some coolumn value in common ..

Comment: I gave example where two tables mapid are the same

Comment: @scaisEdge if two tables mapid are same in that can I connect?

Comment: i have posted an answer  hope is useful

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry for late answer your code also returns empty array http://i.prntscr.com/27264b58ad654871919ca55eed4ca55f.png

Comment: if you don't find the columns that join  the two table  .. is not possibile solve your question .. eventually  .. update you question adding a real data sample and the expected  result

Comment: In that case I want to get json from bdt_mappress_maps by post id which is given in bdt_mappress_posts @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the two table are related  by mapid for both of the tables  you should use a join with on condition

```
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT mapid 
           FROM bdt_mappress_maps 
           INNER JOIN bdt_mappress_posts 
              on (bdt_mappress_maps.mapid = bdt_mappress_posts
                   AND   bdt_mappress_posts.id ='.$postid));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<? $postid = get_the_ID(); 
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT obj FROM bdt_mappress_posts INNER JOIN bdt_mappress_maps WHERE bdt_mappress_posts.mapid = bdt_mappress_maps.mapid AND   bdt_mappress_posts.postid ='.$postid); print_r($results);
?>
```

### Solve the problem

That should only changing the place the rule of the left sql